# csv.reader read from Requests stream: iterator should return strings, not bytes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to stream response to `csv.reader` using `requests.get(url, stream=True)`  to handle quite big data feeds. My code worked fine with `python2.7`. Here's code:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
ret = csv.reader(response.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True), delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar,
    dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for line in ret:
    line.get('name')
```

Unfortunately after migration to python3.6 I got an following error:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I was trying to find some wrapper/decorator that would covert result of `response.iter_lines()` iterator from bytes to string, but no luck with that.
I already tried to use `io` package and also `codecs`. Using `codecs.iterdecode` doesn't split data in lines, it's just split probably by `chunk_size`,
and in this case `csv.reader` is complaining in following way:

```
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Comment: iter_lines() is a generator so I can't decode() on that (?). On the other hand  won't  lambda expression used on generator fill my memory with all the data? I'd like to omit that, thats why I'm streaming it in the first place.

Comment: you're right, that won't work. You have to create a generator which calls the original one and decodes the bytes on-the-fly. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre right, as I thought... I'll probably write some wrapping generator for that, but maybe someone will come up with a prettier solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you could wrap this in a `genexp` and feed decoded lines to it:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    f = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Using some sample data in `3.5` this shuts up `csv.reader`, every line fed to it is first `decoded` in the genexp. Also, I'm using [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) from [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) as is [*generally suggested*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) to automatically `close` the responce.

Comment: Right, genexp is good enough. Thanks for the `closing` part, I wasn't aware of that.